# Trouble with Kivy ScreenManager

Tags: python, kivy

Lately I have some problems with Kivy's Screenmanager. I can't use the `switch_to` method of the manager when accessing it from a `Screen` class. In a `Screen` class: `self.manager.switch_to` gives the error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'switch_to'`. I'm a bit desperate. Below simple app that produces the error.

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

screen1 = True


class Screen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Screen1"))


class Screen2(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Screen2, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Screen2"))


class BlackMenu(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(BlackMenu, self).__init__(**kw)
        if screen1:
            self.manager.switch_to(Screen1())


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mymanager = ScreenManager()
        mymanager.switch_to(BlackMenu(name="black"))
        return mymanager


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: i  think the problem lies in BlackMenu because during construction the instance manager attribute is None.

Answer (score 0):

try declaring your screen manager as a global variable below screen1

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

screen1 = True
screen_manager = ScreenManager()
```

then in your build function add your screens just like:

```
def build(self):
    screen_manager.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))
    screen_manager.add_widget(Screen2(name='screen2'))
    screen_manager.add_widget(BlackMenu(name='black_menu'))
    return screen_manager
```

then in your black screen you could do:

```
class BlackMenu(Screen):
def __init__(self, **kw):
    super(BlackMenu, self).__init__(**kw)
    if screen_manager.current == 'screen1':
        screen_manager.switch_to(Screen1())
```

but keep in mind that switching to a screen removes that screen from screen_manager childs so you have to manage adding it again.
good luck